# How to get current Cart_id/quote_id in plugin file Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quote, plugin

```
namespace Asm\Setsellerid\Plugin;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionFactory;

class Item
{
    /**
     * @var TotalsItemExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $totalsItemExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * ItemConverterPlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param TotalsItemExtensionFactory $totalsItemExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        TotalsItemExtensionFactory $totalsItemExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->totalsItemExtensionFactory = $totalsItemExtensionFactory;
         $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     * @param ItemConverter $subject
     *
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModelToDataObject(
        ItemConverter $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log'); 
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); 
        $logger->addWriter($writer); 
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();

                $logger->info($item->getProduct()->getName());
                $logger->info($item->getProduct()->getPrice());
            }


        $extensionAttributes = $result->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->totalsItemExtensionFactory->create();
        }
        $pointsDelta = 60;
        $extensionAttributes->setMine($pointsDelta);
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Here am trying fetch current **cart_id** but it showing error like..

```
/Setsellerid\/Plugin\/Item.php' on line 57","trace":"Trace is not available.
```

so how to get current **cart id**, thank you in advance

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData(); -> Magento 1 code, Why you use these?

Comment: maybe the tag is wrong sohel

Comment: Thank you for response, am trying to get current quote id

Comment: Please provide me mode detail also code

Comment: I updated the Question please check out thank you.

Comment: Please provide me plugin code which you have defined in di.xml

Comment: ` <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter">
        <plugin name="points-item" type="Asm\Setsellerid\Plugin\Item" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

function functionName(){
    $cartID = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();
    echo "Cart Id : ".$cartID;
}
```

Comment: Trace is not available error. for `$cartID = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();` this line